# Gitlab CI: Build successful even though NPM Error

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've currently got my gitlab-ci.yaml file configured with three stages:
- test
- deploy
- publish

Sometimes NPM errors occur if I or a developer forgets to `--save` an npm package, the `-test` stage doesn't complete properly, yet still returns "build passed". It'll then go to deploy and publish blindly as the pipeline hasn't been cancelled.

How can I make NPM ERR! stop the current stage and stop the rest from running?

I've simulated this issue by intentionally omitting the bluebird package. It affected the entire test/deploy/publish process and essentially bad code was deployed and run on my server:

```
  myClass.js
    .selectSpecificXYZ()
      1) Should return an object containing SUCCESS
      2) should return an object regardless of the input
      3) should return an object with count 0
      4) should return an ABC error 
      5) should return a DEF error

  Array
    #indexOf()
      ✓ should return -1 when the value is not present


  1 passing (87ms)
  5 failing

  1) myClass.js .selectSpecificXYZ() Should return an object containing SUCCESS when a correct myClass reference is passed:
     Error: Cannot find module 'bluebird'
      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (api_system/functions/helpers/database_wrappers.js:5:15)
      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
      at Object.selectXYZByReference (api_system/functions/myClass/myClass.js:55:37)
      at Context.it (api_system/test/myClass/myClassTests.js:19:32)

  2) myClass.js .selectSpecificXYZ() should return an object regardless of the input (to handle success or error):
     Error: Cannot find module 'bluebird'
      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (api_system/functions/helpers/database_wrappers.js:5:15)
      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
      at Object.selectXYZByReference (api_system/functions/myClass/myClass.js:55:37)
      at Context.it (api_system/test/myClass/myClassTests.js:23:32)

  3) myClass.js .selectSpecificXYZ() should return an object with count 0 as there's no value:
     Error: Cannot find module 'bluebird'
      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (api_system/functions/helpers/database_wrappers.js:5:15)
      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
      at Object.selectXYZByReference (api_system/functions/myClass/myClass.js:55:37)
      at Context.it (api_system/test/myClass/myClassTests.js:27:30)

  4) myClass.js .selectSpecificXYZ() should return an Invalid Parameter error :
     AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw error including 'Invalid Parameter' but got 'Cannot find module \'bluebird\''
      at Context.it (api_system/test/myClass/myClassTests.js:33:73)

  5) myClass.js .selectSpecificXYZ() should return an Parameter Too Short error:
     AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw error including 'Parameter Too Short' but got 'Cannot find module \'bluebird\''
      at Context.it (api_system/test/myClass/myClassTests.js:38:79)




npm ERR! Linux 4.4.34-v7+
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "test" "-recursive"
npm ERR! node v7.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! myServer@1.0.0 test: `mocha api_system/test --recursive`
npm ERR! Exit status 5
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myServer@1.0.0 test script 'mocha api_system/test --recursive'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the myServer package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     mocha api_system/test --recursive
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs myServer
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls myServer
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/ci-tests/myServer/npm-debug.log
[32;1m$ cd ..[0;m
[32;1m$ rm -rf myServer[0;m
[32;1m$ cd ..[0;m
[32;1m$ rm -rf ci-tests[0;m
[32;1m$ EOF[0;m
[32;1mBuild succeeded
[0;m
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't include you Travis-CI config or the scripts that you have to run everything but for example, when you have a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
npm install
npm test
```

then the script may still exit with success even when the comments returned errors. What you can do is:

```
#!/bin/sh
npm install \
&& npm test \
|| exit 1
```

to make sure that the script itself returns the error to the OS. This is a general advice not specific to GitLab but I cannot post anything more specific not seeing your config and your scripts.